# Mysql database design for curency exchange website application

Tags: php, mysql, api, database-design

I am building a website that use openexchangerates.org's API.

The API returns a JSON response that looks like:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1391191261,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 3.67328,
    "AFN": 56.4876,
    "ALL": 103.8916,
    "AMD": 411.612997,
    /* 165 currencies */
    "YER": 215.057,
    "ZAR": 11.14973,
    "ZMK": 5253.075255,
    "ZMW": 5.579003,
    "ZWL": 322.355006
  }
}
```

Now I am thinking about the correct table database structure for this value. It displays exchange rates for even years ago. I will probably not use that but only the rates within a month range. How to handle this type of situation for display curency comparations for different days and so on?

Table:

```
curency \ rate    \ date

AED     \ 3.67328 \ 31-01-2014
AFN     \ 56.4876 \ 31-01-2014

\* and so on for this date... then older rates for past dates *\

AED     \ 3.12367 \ 30-01-2014
AFN     \ 55.2345 \ 30-01-2014
```

Is this a good database design? What else i should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a table like this:

```
id | currency | rate | start-date
```

When you're searching for a currency, you just have to look up the entry with the correct date (latest start-date, that is still earlier than the date you're searching for).

Select:  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date < searchDate ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;`

If the rate changes, you only have to add a new row, with the current SYSDATE.

Select:  `INSERT INTO table VALUES (id, 'EUR', '1.4', SYSDATE);`

So yes, I think this table is ideal.

**BUT:** A problem can appear, if you are deleting entries - and suddenly, there are no rows with "USD" anymore, and your database forgot about US-Dollar.

Let's take a look at an example - we know 2 currencies, and stored it in the table:

```
id | currency | rate | start-date
---------------------------------
 1    USD        1      1.1.1970
 2    EUR        2      1.1.1970
 3    EUR        3      5.1.1970
```

If we want to delete the first entry (USD), we can do it. The problem that appears is, that we don't have an entry with USD anymore - and our database stores only rates for 1 currency.

In this case, you might want to use 2 tables with a foreign-key.

See this example:

**table 1:**

```
id | currency
```

**table 2:**

```
id | fk_currency | rate | start-date
```

The first table stores all currencies, that are avaiable. And the second table stores the rate. The column `fk_currency` is a foreign key on table1, and contains the id of the currency.

If we delete a rate from table2, we still have the currency stored in the other table. The database didn't forget it.

Comment: I don't think you want "earliest start-date that's higher than the date you're searching for." I think you want "latest start-date that's lower than or equal to the date you're searching for." Else you're always picking rates that haven't happened yet.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I didn't understand how to use the two tables. Can you explain me a little more? What is "fk_currency" and "start-date"?

Can you add some values to the tables to understand how are they linked? I don't really understand how are the tables connected.

Comment: @m3tsys I explaind the 2 tables in more detail. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Thank you, i understand now. But... i need to declare that foreign key in mysql in some way?

Comment: If you're declaring your table, use this syntax: `FOREIGN KEY (fk_currency) REFERENCES table1(id));`

Comment: Or you could also declare your table normaly, and use `ALTER TABLE table2 ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY fk_currency REFERENCES table1(id);`